# Por qué NO se ejecuta el código después de 10 segundos?

Tags: nodejs

Tengo este código en *nodejs*, que lo que intento hacer es que cuando carga el servidor http, escriba un texto , pero lo importante es que deben pasar 10 segundos, pero el texto se muestra de inmediato y no espera los 10 segundos.

```
var http = require("http"), url = require("url");

function web (req, res){
 res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
 var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
 router = router(pathname);
 res.write(router);
 res.end();
}
http.createServer(web).listen(90);

function router (path){

 function esperar (n) {
 var ini = new Date().getTime(), segundos = n*1000; // Tiempo inicial
 while(new Date().getTime() < (ini + segundos)); // Esperar n segundos
 }
esperar(10);
return `Estas en ${path}, y han pasado ${n} segundos` 
}
```

Entonces, por qué NO espera los 10 segundos, cuál es mi error ?

Comment: Nodejs es asíncrono por lo que no es lineal, es decir no siempre se ejecuta las lineas en orden, para hacer esperar en node prueba coon settimeout
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849106/how-does-settimeout-work-in-node-js

Comment: En principio tu codigo no funciona dado a que 'n' no esta definida dentro de router, sino dentro de esperar. Una vez que corrijas esto seguimos

Comment: Si no tuviese recompensa votaría para cerrar: El código falla al ejecutarse, pero si quitamos la variable  n del string, el problema no se puede reproducir: el código se queda bloqueado durante  10 segundos y luego devuelve el valor

Comment: ya está arreglado, la función se llama dentro de la funcion router

Comment: @EduardoSebastian agrega tu respuesta para que no pierdas la recompensa!, saludos!

Comment: Aún no tengo respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SOLUCIÓN

La mejor opción para hacerlo sin demasiadas complicaciones, es utilizar la función `setTimeout(TUFUNCION, TIEMPODEESPERA)`, como indica @Federico Madoery.

Intenta organizar tu programa de manera que puedas trabajarlo a través de funciones, que sería la manera más apropiada de manejar esto. Aquí tienes el ejemplo de como utilizar setTimeout():

```
function funcion1() {
    // Lo que sucede inmediatamente
    console.log('Hola.');
}

function funcion2() {
    // Lo que ocurre tras la pausa
    console.log('¿Qué hace?');
}

// Llama tu primera función, que se ejecuta de inmediato
funcion1();

// Executa el resto tras la pausa de 10 segundos
setTimeout(funcion2, 10000);
```

## EXPLICACIÓN

Nodejs es **asíncrono**, o sea, no siempre va a terminar una operacion totalmente antes de realizar la siguiente, que es justo lo que ocurre con tu función de espera.

Nodejs busca optimizar recursos, así que, por describirlo de alguna manera, usa procesamiento *libre* mientras *espera a que se cumpla la condición* y por ello avanza con las siguientes operaciones durante la *espera*.

Esto significa que el while SI se esta realizando, pero como esto mantendrá a la maquina "sin hacer nada" un rato, Nodejs continúa con la siguiente operación mientras la condición del while se cumple.

#### NOTAS

*Mi respuesta se basa en [esta pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time#14249571), por si deseas buscar más información.

*Como indican los comentarios, es posible que hayan algunos otros errores en tu codigo que no permitan la correcta ejecución de tu programa. Sería bueno que lo revises completamente.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te paso dos posibles soluciones, que en mi caso me han funcionado.

```
 function mensaje() {
        console.log("Tu mensaje");
    }

// el tiempo es en ms
setTimeout(mensaje, 3000);
```

Otra forma mas elegante podría ser crear una función que "duerma" el sistema durante X tiempo y luego imprimes el mensaje.

```
const util = require('util');
const sleep = util.promisify(setTimeout);
await sleep(1000); // También en ms
```

Answer (score -1):

Tambien puede hacer la función que te permita ella misma realizar la espera y mostrar el mensaje

```
var http = require("http"), url = require("url");

function web (req, res){
 res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
 var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
 router = router(pathname);
 res.write(router);
 res.end();
}
http.createServer(web).listen(90);

function router (path){

 function msgconespera (n, mensaje) {
 var ini = new Date().getTime(), segundos = n*1000; // Tiempo inicial
 while(new Date().getTime() < (ini + segundos)); // Esperar n segundos
 return mensaje;
 }
mensaje=`Estas en ${path}, y han pasado ${n} segundos` ;
msgconespera(10, mensaje);
}
```